# which category/type of sorting algorithm is this?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, bubble-sort

This might be a dumb question. 
However, I am a little confused about categorizing this sort

here I am comparing the first element with all elements and then swapping with greater.

 then picking the second element compared with all next and then swapping with greater

```java
class Sort{

     public static void main(String[] arg)
     {

         System.out.println("Sort");

         int[] unsorted = {2,5,2,5,3,3,6,2,7,3,1,84,3};

         
         for(int i=0;i<unsorted.length;i++)
         {
            for(int j=i;j<unsorted.length;j++)
            {
                if(unsorted[i] > unsorted[j])
                {
                    swap(unsorted,i,j);
                }
            }      
         }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));


     }

    public static void swap(int[] arr,int i,int j)
    {
        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=tmp;
    }


 }
```

Comment: Bubble sort....

Comment: @Asgar why would you think that?

Comment: @Asgar, bubble sort swaps *neighboring* values only.

Comment: By bad, thanks for the lesson guys\

Comment: @user16320675 While there’s no reason to start the inner loop at `i`, swapping multiple times through the inner  loop is not necessarily slower, may be faster, and may be more efficient particularly on some embedded architectures.

Answer (score 1):

That’s selection sort. You can tell because after iteration `i` of the outer loop, all elements of the array up to index `i` are in their final positions. The only nonstandard bit is that the active element is swapped each time a smaller element is found; this is not the case in the “classic” selection sort but is common in actual implementations (particularly in embedded systems).